# add pagination to gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pagination, page-index-changed

what i want to happen is to have a pagination to have a clean look at the data.
here is my html code for gridview:

```
<asp:gridview ID = "grid" runat="server"  AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="gdview_PageIndexChanging">
```

and code behind:

```
public static string cs = "Server=PAULO;Database=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security=true";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["New"] != null)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                con.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '" + Session["New"] +"'";
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);




                Label2.Text += Session["New"].ToString();
                linkLogout.Visible = true;
                //linkOrderHistory.Visible = true;
                Label2.Visible = true;
                linkViewProfile.Visible = true;
                grid.DataSource = dt;
                grid.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }
    private void CustomBindData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '" + Session["New"] + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
    protected void gdview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomBindData();
        grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
```

somehow my code is not working. it has the pages but when i click on page 2, no data is shown. i think it has something to do on how i get the data from the sql. any tricks on this?

Comment: put the databinding section inside a function, and call it in two places, one during load and one iside the pageIndexChanging before grid.DataBind();

Comment: not enough, you need to set source in the custom funtion

Comment: @ARUN what am i missing?

Comment: yes sir @ARUN thank you :)

Comment: @ARUN sir can you help me out on this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562604/avoid-local-host-id-to-be-edited-by-customers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added

```
private void CustomBindData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "SELECT * FROM CustomerDetails Where CustomerName = '" + Session["New"] + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        grid.DataSource = dt;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
    protected void gdview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomBindData();
        grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this

```
protected void gdview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

use the following..In page load store the datasource to session which your were using for the gridview and do the following like,

```
Session[gridviewsouce] = dt; //dataTable which you were using in page_load
```

and in page indexchanging function..

```
protected void gdview_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    grid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    DataTabel dt = Session[gridviewsouce] as DataTable;
    grid.DataSource = dt;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: dont store huge data in session , use viewstate[], server memory may ran out very fast

Comment: @ARUN, is there any limit for server memory??just to clarify?

Comment: Yes, depends on the server, some times from 2GB to 26GB on google dedicated server , there is paging and other mechanisms to over come this limit, but speed will decrease as the hard disk is used for making virtual ram.. like that.. simply saying, there is limt